# jQuery while object.hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to find a way to stop a function at a certain point until something does not have a  specific class anymore. I cannot change the place where this class is being assigned and removed because it's a plugin.

I was thinking of doing something like this

```
function DoSomething() {
        while ($('div.divControl').hasClass('playing'))
        {
            //Wait here
        }
    };
```

Is this the correct way to go?

Comment: Why not edit the plugin itself? This will most likely cause a crash.

Comment: You should really check if you can't work with the plugin itself... "playing" sounds like it's kinf of a video or audio player. If it's a good plugin, I imagine there will be an `onstop` or `onfinish` event (or something like that) you can listen for.

Comment: And if there aren't any onstop or onfinish events, it wouldn't be hard to add them.

Comment: I've done as suggested by the comments here, I modified the plugin and  added stop and start events. Gave the answer to Jivings as it is most relevant to what I was initially searching for. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will block so the element will never be changed, as no other code will execute.
What you need to use is an interval:

```
var interval = setInterval(DoSomething, 500);

function DoSomething() {
        if ($('div.divControl').hasClass('playing'))
        {
            // Do something
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    };
```

This will execute the function every half second. The interval will be cancelled after the function succeeds.

Comment: Please don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, it uses `eval`.  Pass functions.  I edited your answer to reflect this.

Comment: Please don't use text in your setInterval argument.  Just pass an actual function reference.  And, you will need to use the same capitalization in both places (function reference and function name) because what you have now won't work.

Comment: I thought about doing a setInterval as well, but if I set it to a short interval wouldn't it be just like an infinite loop.

Comment: No. A loop will block completely but setinterval doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

No, that will just hang the browser as it goes into an infinite loop.

Your best bet (as best I can think at the moment anyhow) is to do a setTimeout on the function and have it check to see if it your div still has the class every quarter of a second or so.

Still, not nice at all =[